# How do you call an async method within a closure (like within map) in Rust?

Tags: rust, async-await, closures

I have the following:

```
struct Foo {
   id: u32,
}
impl Foo {
async fn get(id: u32) -> Result<Self, Box<dyn Error>> {
   Ok(Self{ id })
}

async fn something() {
    let ids = vec![1000, 1001];
// conceptually, I'd like to do something like this...
    let result: Vec<Foo> = ids.iter().map(|id| Foo::get(id).await.unwrap()).collect();
}
```

Obviously, I can't use the await within the enclosure. I've tried several different ways of using futures::streams with iter(), map() and collect() and await, but haven't been able to get past the Vec. Any suggestions?

Comment: convert the vector to stream

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can wrap the body of the closure in an `async` block, turning your `ids` into a vec of `Future<Output = Foo>`, and then use the `futures::future::join_all` function to await them all at once (or, perhaps even better, use the `try_join_all` function to get a result):

```
extern crate futures;

use futures::future;
use std::error::Error;

struct Foo {
    id: u32,
}
impl Foo {
    async fn get(id: u32) -> Result<Self, Box<dyn Error>> {
        Ok(Self { id })
    }
}

async fn something() {
    let ids = vec![1000, 1001];
    let result: Vec<Foo> =
        future::try_join_all(ids.iter().map(|id| Foo::get(*id)))
            .await
            .unwrap();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=811918b96316d539470096c39030c52b).

**Edit**: Obviously, with the `try_join_all` function it's unnecessary to use an async block.